# After installing dotmap in an environement I still get ImportError: No module named dotmap when trying to run the notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, importerror

Today I come with a two in one set of issues that's on the verge of making me smash my computer to pieces! So please I would greatly appreciate any help as I've been stuck on it for two days now.

I have a project where osmnx is required, so I follow the install instructions [provided](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx#installation). Which means that I created a dedicated (clean) environment for it. Within this project there is a notebook that I should run, which leads me to `ImportError: No module named dotmap`. So I say okay, and install dotmap in the environment through conda install.

Now heres the situation, even though I installed it sucessfully in the environment, I keep getting the same error when I run the notebook! So I think maybe I should reinstall dotmap using pip through conda prompt. But when I use pip install in the dedicated ox environment, I get failed to create process. So I say okay, lets install it again through conda install but it still doesn't work.

I see that the dotmap is being called from a main.py document. So I decide to check the main.py document by installing spyder through anaconda navigtor. Once it's installed I click launch and spyder never launches! I try to launch from the conda prompt and I just get `Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\THESIS\.conda\envs\ox2\python.exe C:\Users\THESIS\.conda\envs\ox2\Scripts\spyder-script.py`.

At the moment I ran out of ideas of what to do as I tried to work around it numerous times. Before questions get asked (and I hope someone asks something), I'd like to say that I already:

- Reinstalled anaconda navigator
- Tried created numerous environments in various different ways of installing osmnx and dotmap
- Tried reinstalling and launching spyder in numerous different ways (Same thing is happening with Jupyterlab)
- And probably some other things that I can not remember now off the top of my head

I know I sound fed up and angry at the moment but I just can not understand how I did not find a solution to this (what should be) simple issue.

All in all, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you made sure that you set up a jupyter kernel for the new environment and also selected it in the notebooks settings?

Comment: Yeah I have. Also, I did a clean install of anaconda just now where I managed to finally get dotmap to work. However now I get the issue that Jupyter nor Jupyterlab want to launch from the anaconda navigator nor the conda prompt.

The conda prompt returns this error ```Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\mmari\.conda\envs\ox\python.exe C:\Users\mmari\.conda\envs\ox\Scripts\jupyter-script.py '```

Comment: Try launching them from the anaconda prompt

Comment: The ```Unable to create process``` error was from running jupyter-notebook from the prompt

Answer (score 1):

Following droptop recommendation, I actually just did a full clean (another one) reinstall of anaconda where I deleted almost everything that I could.

I installed it again and it's working now! Thanks for the help anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Your fresh anaconda install should have `jupyter`, `jupyterlab` and `spyder` in the `base` environment. Starting the anaconda prompt and typing in `jupyter notebook` should launch jupyter.

Try activating your `ox2` environment with another prompt, and follow through from step 3 of this post https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084